# artifactId и version подсвечивается красным в Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, backend

вот cкрин ->

[image]

Пытаюсь сконфигурировать Spring MVC в Maven. Но artifactId и version подсвечивается красным. И ничего не добавляется. Подскажите, что делать? По возможности скиньте ссылку на ресурс, который решает мою проблему.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.zaurtregulov.spring.mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring_course_mvc</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>spring_course_mvc Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Comment: @RomanC, спасибо разобрался. Дело было в том, что я не подгрузил новые зависимости.

Comment: Можете оформить это как ответ, или удалить совсем. Ваш вопрос не представляет особого интереса и поэтому будет закрыт. Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все нормально, нужно просто подгрузить. Если работаете из intellij, нажмите комбинацию ctrl+shift+O, по другим средам см в справочнике горячие клавиши

Answer (score 0):

Если работаешь в IDEA,то сделай Reload All Maven Projects.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло